# How to properly change Tab Background in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, tabwidget

I am a newbie to Android Development, and facing this particular problem while changing TabBackground Image.

As you can see in the attached Image, there is a thin gray line. And I am unable to figure out where is it coming from. Can you please assist me in removing it.

I have checked there is no padding anywhere, and android:layout_width="wrap_content" and             android:layout_height="wrap_content".

[image]

**Actual Tab Background Image**

[image: Actual Tab Background Image]

Answer (score 0):

Just in XML file where you have mentioned a tag called ***"Tab-widget"***, in it write

```
 android:tabStripEnabled="false"
```

It will make sure that the bottom line under all the tabs will disappear.